# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to show the list of values in MatBottomSheet from another component. I am always getting error like below.

> **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null**

[image]

I am passing values from **testcomponent** like below:

```
  openBottomSheet(order) {
    const id = order;
    console.log('====>' + JSON.stringify(id));
    console.log('====>' + JSON.stringify(order));
    const MatBottomSheetRef = this._bottomSheet.open(ProductbottomComponent, {
      data: id,
    });
    this._bottomSheet.open(ProductbottomComponent);
  }
```

And calling above component to another **ProductbottomComponent typescript** is

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/getorder/' + this.authService.namespace + '/' + this.data.id)
        .subscribe(result => {
          this.model = result;
          console.log('-====>' + JSON.stringify(this.model));
        });
}
```

**productbottom.component.html (here is a part of my template)**

```
<table cellpadding="10" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr style="text-align:left">
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let del of model.products">
                <td>{{del.name}}</td>
                <td>{{del.quantity}}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Getting values in console log

```
{"id":"0504fd10-1278-41bf-b052-a459c1e37998","products":[{"productid":"","name":"Snowball","price":"5.00","quantity":1}],"order":"Order - 1005","name":"test123","email":"test@gmail.com","mobile":"111111111","status":"Packing In Progress","note":"","packedby":"test78","packedbyId":"1bd9632a-406a-4212-a8c0-d0732ab42635","packeddate":"","deliveredby":"","deliveredbyId":"","delivereddate":"","type":"testPickup","address1":"","address2":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","createddate":"2020-07-06 22:07:17","lastModifieddate":"2020-07-06 22:07:17"}
```

Help me to fix it!

Comment: `this.data` seems to be null. Where is it initialized? How do you call `ngOnInit()`? As this is not an arrow function, did you think of binding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to comment this line:

`this._bottomSheet.open(ProductbottomComponent);`

It's not needed!

Answer (score 1):

seems like this.data is null
[image]

u are opening ProductbottomComponent twice  once with data and once without data
[image]

Use just

```
    const MatBottomSheetRef = this._bottomSheet.open(ProductbottomComponent, {
      data: id,
    });

   // this._bottomSheet.open(ProductbottomComponent); // remove it
```